# What is the name of Worf's Exercises?

Tags: star-trek, worf

We regularly see Worf doing some sort of exercises that are similar to Tai Chi and I was just wondering what these were?  I know we see him doing this in the TNG episodes *Parallels* (where he proceeds to break a table) for some reference and names it (although I didn't catch the name) in *Birthright Part II* when teaching to the Klingons.

Comment: From the question title, I thought you were referring to the early TNG episodes where Worf would battle some constructs in the holodeck with some goofy looking melee weapons. This was the [Klingon Calisthenics Program](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon_calisthenics_program), apparently. Anyways, have an upvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading through the [Memory Alpha page on Worf](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Worf), these exercises are called '[Mok'bara](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mok%27bara)'.  They are:

> *a Klingon form of martial arts*

and said to be like meditation, clearing the mind.

This is an image of it for those needing to jog their memory:
[image: Worf leading a Mok'bara group]

Comment: I just realized... in World of WarCraft, Mok'bara are a race of lobster-creatures. Gotta love Blizzard and their Star Trek references!